# Помогите разобраться! Нужно ли после уточнения «покупателям» ставить запятую? и нужно ли там тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Дело в том, что конкуренция имеет много плюсов: она способствует развитию научно-технического прогресса, повышению эффективности производства и улучшению качества выпускаемой продукции, она позволяет устанавливать свободную цену на рынке, дает возможность выбора товаров и услуг клиентам - покупателям(-), более того, она ограничивает возможность возникновения монополий, ну и конечно же, снижает издержки самих конкурентов.

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему - можно отметить его галочкой (под нижним серым треугольником слева от ответа).

Answer (score 0):

Запятая необходима и её надо оставить: она замыкает перечисляемое. Одного тире достаточно, ведь покупатели (как можно понять) — основные клиенты рынка. Есть потребность в тчк/зпт для деления предложения из-за его длины надвое — перед местоимением *она*. Возможно в этом месте (судя по контексту) надо поставить не тчк/зпт, а двоеточие.

Comment: Тогда перед "более того, она" тоже нужно тчк/зпт и "более того" лучше убрать, так как оно ссылается на предыдущую часть.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно ставить **запятую**.

**Одно тире опускается, если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая**:
*Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор — весы, то понял бы источник ошибки.   Используя специальное устройство для дыхания человека под водой — акваланг, можно погружаться на глубину в десятки метров.

Среди актёров передвижной труппы Сергея Эйзенштейна были юноши, впоследствии ставшие известными кинорежиссёрами, — Григорий Александров, Иван Пырьев, а также актёр Максим Штраух.*
Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111 (см. примечания)

При этом после тире определяется понятие:
*клиенты — это покупатели*.

Это если выбирать из двух вариантов (запятая или тире). Но "покупателей" лучше **взять в скобки**, так как это не основная информация, а вспомогательная. Всё-таки здесь слово "клиенты" важнее.

Answer (score 0):

С точки зрения общих пунктуационных правил при таком построении фразы там, конечно, **запятая**. Тире в этом случае "поглощается запятой (ссылки вам уже дали в других ответах).

Но беда в том, что такое построение фразы здесь совершенно не по контексту. Фразу лучше переделать. Приложение с обособленным с помощью тире выглядит очень натянуто и зрительно воспринимается плохо. По смыслу посмотрите, если клиент и покупатель - это одно лицо, то зачем говорить о нем дважды? А если это разные лица (как можно предположить, клиент - это в потребитель услуг, а покупатель - товаров), то здесь нужно не приложение, а обычное перечисление.

***...дает возможность выбора товаров и услуг клиентам и покупателям...***
или так
***...дает возможность выбора товаров и услуг клиентам (покупателям), ...***

Заодно и проблемы пунктуации решаются.

===

Что до примеров (которые цитирует oleedd, ссылаясь на Розенталя), то там явно другой контекст.

*Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор — весы, то понял бы источник ошибки. Используя специальное устройство для дыхания человека под водой — акваланг, можно погружаться на глубину в десятки метров.

Среди актёров передвижной труппы Сергея Эйзенштейна были юноши, впоследствии ставшие известными кинорежиссёрами, — Григорий Александров, Иван Пырьев, а также актёр Максим Штраух.*

С помощью приложения здесь вводится новое понятие или раскрывается предыдущее (во втором случае, кстати, довольно неуклюже получается, фамилии режиссеров  противопоставляются фамилии актера - зачем?). Это типичное употребление такого обособленного приложения. Отношение же между понятиями "клиент" и "покупатель" не как не могут быть сведены к тому, что второе раскрывает первое. О вводе нового понятия и речи нет. Так что автор, похоже, несколько перемудрил, пытаясь оформить свою мысль с помощью этого приема.

Comment: **В третьем** (не втором) примере "и" не сильно звучит, а "а также" отделяет режиссёров от актёра, чтобы не подумали, что он и актёр, и режиссёр одновременно, и он юношей на тот момент не являлся: *были юноши, а также актёр*.

Comment: Я так не считаю.

Comment: Ну, у вас случай. Так у Розенталя 3 примера. Про режиссёров - третий.

Comment: Вы так спешите комментировать ответ по пустякам, что избавляете меня от необходимости давать ответ по существу. Спасибо вам за это.

Comment: Ну я сразу отвечаю. Не считаете так? Что противопоставлять не нужно, или что? Тогда как бы вы написали это предложение?

Comment: Я не считаю нужным комментировать ваши ответы, данные в таком режиме.

Comment: И вообще ---------

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101449/discussion-between-behemothus-and-oleedd).

Comment: В этом вопросе, в принципе, согласен с вами. Но здесь "а также" имеет добавочный оттенок. Тут не противопоставление. Это не совсем естественно. Но оно требуется для разделения структуры предложения.

Comment: Тут в одном ответе предлагают написать через дефис -"клиентам-покупателям". Но думаю, что лучше звучит наоборот - "покупателям-клиентам". Интересно, что вы об этом думаете. Лучше в самом ответе прокомментировать.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что конкуренция имеет много плюсов: она способствует развитию научно-технического прогресса, повышению эффективности производства и улучшению качества выпускаемой продукции, она позволяет устанавливать свободную цену на рынке, дает возможность выбора товаров и услуг клиентам-покупателям, более того, она ограничивает возможность возникновения монополий ну и, конечно же, снижает издержки самих конкурентов.

Покупатель - приложение, то есть определение, выраженное нарицательным существительным. Определяемое слово - клиент, так же выражено нарицательным существительным. Это один из тех случаев, когда между определяемым словом и приложением пишется дефис. Еще примеры: ученый-филолог, учитель-француз, художник-баталист.

Здесь приведена таблица "Дефис в приложениях" - Дефис при приложении. https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/defis-prilozhenii.html

Запятая перед "ну" не нужно, так как "ну" в данном случае частица.

Выделяется запятыми междометие ну.

Оно обычно стоит перед глаголом в форме повелительного наклонения и употребляется для выражения нетерпения и побуждения к действию:

Ну, рассказывай скорей!

Частица ну, как правило, употребляется в усилительном значении и запятой не отделяется: Ну и гроза! давно такой не бывало! Ну зачем так резко? Ну что за вопрос!

Comment: А куда у нас делась запятая перед **ну и**? Вы считаете, что она не нужна?

Comment: У нас в вопросе не дефис, а **тире**. Иначе бы вопроса о втором дефисе не возникло. Через дефис пишутся единые понятия. У вас всё-таки неправильно пунктуация получилась. "Ну" — частица, но она не относится к предыдущему глаголу, и запятая перед ней нужна. Там пунктуация была правильная.